# How to display images of type .jpeg or .gif or .tiff in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I am facing a problem while displaying the image in iphone. I used the below code but it work only for .png files.

```
      UIImageView* imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6,10, 80, 80)];
      imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customerListObject.customerImage]]];
      [myView addSubview:imageView];
      [imageView release];
```

I could not display the other types of image file, Please suggest me the solution.

Thank you,
Madan Mohan

Comment: Did you try with local images and [ UIImage imageNamed:@"" ] ?

Comment: Its working with it, but i need to display with other types

Comment: Have you confirmed that your calls to [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:] and [UIImage imageWithData:] are not returning nil?  That is, are you getting the data from the URL, and is that data being turned into a UIImage successfully?

Comment: @Ryan :Yes, If we take .png then it is working fine. But, when we take other types like .jif or jpeg then it was returning nil.

Comment: Sounds like it's having trouble decoding your non-png images.  Is anything printed to the device console when decoding fails?

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imagename" ofType:@"png"]];
```

And then replace imagename and png with your file name and type.

Comment: I am getting the image url from parser, how can i use NSBundle