# How to display images of type .jpeg or .gif or .tiff in iphone sdk using objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image

I am facing a problem while displaying the image in iphone. I used the below code but it work only for .png files.

```
  UIImageView* imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6,10, 80, 80)];
  imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customerListObject.customerImage]]];
  [myView addSubview:imageView];
  [imageView release];
```

I could not display the other types of image file, Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display  images of type .jpeg or .gif or .tiff  in iphone sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923527/how-to-display-images-of-type-jpeg-or-gif-or-tiff-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: You'll need to post links to some sample images. All of the formats you listed are natively supported, so the problem is not in your code as show. One notable limitation is that iOS will not load images with dimensions larger than 1024x1024.

Comment: Sorry, So it can load lesser than 1024x1024, then how can I load it

Comment: not only duplicate but reposted. please do not repost, but alter ur old question.