# Is there a way to add images of type .jpeg , .gif and tiff... etc in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image

I got one problem that how can i display the .jpeg and other type of files in iphone sdk. Is there any solution to this. please help me.

Thank you,
Madan Mohan.

Comment: Instead of posting the same questions three times in just 18 hours, you should stick with the first and try to give more informations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923527/how-to-display-images-of-type-jpeg-or-gif-or-tiff-in-iphone-sdk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930625/how-to-display-images-of-type-jpeg-or-gif-or-tiff-in-iphone-sdk-using-objectiv

Comment: why are you re posting the same question for the third time?please follow stack overflow guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a UIImage like this:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpeg"];
```

Display it in a UIImageView:

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
```

And add the UIImageView as subview to your existing view:

```
[view adsdSubview:myImageView];
```

Comment: I have an image url like this : http://static.gamesradar.com/images/mb/GamesRadar/us/Games/X/X-Men%20Arcade/Bulk%20Viewer/360%20PS3/2010-10-11/192.168.30.167-image36_bmp_jpgcopy--game_thumbnail.jpg

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to display image from the URL

```
NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourURL"]];

UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 250, 250)];
imgView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```